# MCV4 And Enitiy Framework. Without been able to directly connect to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very strange situation which I am currently faced with.  I have been passed a project to uplift a website to use MVC4 & the enitiy framework.  However due to the way that the original implementation was undertaken the database access is not direct from the website it's handed to a separate middle-ware application which we pass the name of a sql transaction we would like to have executed & the required parameters, this then returns us a datatable object.

My Question is this Without having to remove this middle-ware process could I create a MVC4 App with the use of the enitiy framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create an MVC4 app - you'll just have to create a custom model - but I would suggest that even if using EF is possible, it will be more effort than it is worth, and involve too many compromises and hacks.

Comment: Thanks for that.  So it looks like I need to look into the reasoning behind the middle-ware.  To see about removing it and getting the web app to hook straight in to it.

Comment: @ToxicBlotch That depends. If it absolutely has to be EF, then yes, but if the middleware is working, I'd also question the requirement to reinvent it in EF